# How to get Candy XL

Tags: pokemon-go

With the recent release of level 40+, you'll need Candy XL to level Pokémon over level 40. How do I obtain (more) Candy XL?

[image: Mewtwo level 40]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [this](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/xl-candy-guide-how-to-get-power-up-costs-and-mechanics/) guide, you can get XL Candy from various different sources. In order to obtain any XL candy from the following methods, your trainer level must be level 40 or above.

- Catching regular spawn: 0 - 3 XL Candy (unaffected by Pinap berries)
- Catching raid boss: 1 XL Candy (unaffected by Pinap berries)
- <strike>Trading: 1 XL Candy (can be either both trainers or just one)</strike>

  - [Currently disabled](https://twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1333493766620123136)
- Hatching:

  - 5km Egg: maximum 16 XL Candy
  - 10km Egg: maximum 24 XL Candy
- Transfer: 1 XL Candy
- Exchange: 100 regular Candy -> 1 XL Candy

  - You can do this by going into a Pokemon, viewing the options, and click on the option to exchange candy
  - Based on the comments, this menu might only appear after receiving your first XL candy

When catching, transferring, or trading, receiving XL candy is not a guaranteed chance. I received 1 XL candy when transferring a Beldum, not did not receive any XL Candy when transferring 2 Gibles

Comment: When is the exchange menu activated?

Comment: @Pureferret I updated my answer. Hopefully that answers your question :)

Comment: @Purefect, this exchange option showed for me when I got the first Candy XL. It's one of the options in a specific Pokemon menu (e.g. the menu button on the lower right in the graph in the question)

Comment: @mathius711  that must be why I've not seen the menu yet.

Answer (score 0):

Higher level Pokemon are also more likely to award XL candies, both when catching and when transferring.  I recently transferred 38 Meltan and tracked my results. I received 8 XL candies from the 19 largest ones I transferred (over 300CP) and only 4 XL candies for the smallest 19. Unfortunately I didn't track my results while catching, only transferring.